# Combine objects values into the single object

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have two objects -

```
a = {0:"hai",1:"hello"}
b = {0:"what",1:"you"}
```

I want to get a resulting object on merge of the following format

```
c = {0:"hai",1:"hello",2:"what",3:"you"}
```

I tried different merge techniques, but fail to achieve this. What are the optimal ways of achieving the above?

Comment: I want the previous values to exist as well. None of the answers mentioned help .

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that essentially converts the objects to arrays then merges them together using Array.prototype.concat:

```js
Object.assign([], {0:"hai",1:"hello"}).concat(Object.assign([], {0:"what",1:"you"}))
```

Comment: Above returns the array, whereas OP has requested an object

Comment: Arrays are just objects with more helper methods. If you really hate the helper methods then you can just throw in an `Object.assign({}, stuff)` where `stuff` is the code I posted above.

Comment: *'...you can just'* what I *can do* is [whole lot better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61408198/11299053), however we're talking here about your solutions, which is, basically, ***a half*** of the answer

Answer (score 0):

#### Universal approach for arbitrary number of input objects

---

Considering you want to merge your objects (with overlapping keys) in the order of appearance, I may suggest the following (works for arbitrary number of input objects)

- extract [`Object.values()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of your source objects
- combine those values into single output with [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Following is a live-demo as a proof of a concept:

```js
const a = {0:"hai",1:"hello"},
      b = {0:"what",1:"you"},
      
      mergeObjects = (...args) => ({...args.flatMap(Object.values)}),
      
      c = mergeObjects(a,b)
      
console.log(c)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

However, since you don't seem to be making use of object keys and plain array may be what's desired, you may go as simple as that:

```js
const a = {0:"hai",1:"hello"},
      b = {0:"what",1:"you"},
      
      mergeObjects = (...args) => args.flatMap(Object.values),
      
      c = mergeObjects(a,b)
      
console.log(c)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```