# Combine two array objects with exactly the same structure

Tags: javascript, angular

I am implementing a service that extracts a list of blacklist terms from a json file.

```
@Injectable()
export class BlacklistService {
  private readonly BLACKLIST_FOLDER = './assets/data/web-blacklist';
  private readonly blacklistEnglishTerms: any;
  private readonly blacklistFrenchTerms: any;

  constructor(
    public httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.blacklistEnglishTerms = this.httpClient.get(`${this.BLACKLIST_FOLDER}/en.json`);
    this.blacklistFrenchTerms = this.httpClient.get(`${this.BLACKLIST_FOLDER}/fr.json`);
  }

  public getAllBlackListTerms(): Observable<any> {
    return combineLatest([
      this.blacklistEnglishTerms,
      this.blacklistFrenchTerms
    ]);
  }
}
```

For reference, each json file looks like this:

```
{
  "blacklist": [
    "...",
    "...",
    "..."
  ]
}
```

I retrieve all the items in my component as follows:

```
this.blacklistService.getAllBlackListTerms().pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(blacklistTerms => {
  console.log(blacklistTerms);
});
```

`blacklistTerms` returns as an array of 2 array objects. How do I combine these two objects into one object (both have the same structure).

[image]

Comment: You may check out [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61408198/11299053)

Comment: Try with `blacklistTerms.flatMap(x => x.blacklist)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given, you have known results, i.e. You know that the results of the bolth the Observbales would have only one key: blackList you can modify your service like:

```
public getAllBlackListTerms(): Observable<any> {
    return zip(
        this.blacklistEnglishTerms,
        this.blacklistFrenchTerms
    ).pipe(map([first, second]) => {
        return { blackList: [...first.blackList, ...second.blackList]};
    });
}
```

I have also, replaced `combineLatest()` with `zip()`, because you probably want the results only when both has emitted values.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following approach

```js
var s  = [{a:[1,2,3]},{a:[6,7,8]}]
var obj = {}
for(let i in s){
    if(!obj['a']){obj['a'] = s[i]['a'];}
    else{
   obj['a'].push(...s[i]['a'])
    }
}

console.log(obj)
```

but here you need to manually define `blacklist`

Answer (score 2):

Blacklist is an array - even a simple concat can help !!

```js
var blacklistEnglishTerms = {
  "blacklist": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ]
}
var blacklistFrenchTerms = {
  "blacklist": [
    "e",
    "f",
    "g"
  ]
}
console.log(blacklistEnglishTerms.blacklist.concat(blacklistFrenchTerms.blacklist));
```

Answer (score 2):

> i think you please use concat().
> the concat() is used for combine two arrays.

```js
public getAllBlackListTerms(): Observable<any> {
    
   return combineLatest = this.blacklistEnglishTerms.concat(this.blacklistFrenchTerms);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) like `blacklistTerms.flatMap(x => x.blacklist)`

```
this.blacklistService.getAllBlackListTerms().pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(blacklistTerms => {
  console.log(blacklistTerms.flatMap(x => x.blacklist));
});
```

Test is below.

```js
let blacklistTerms = [
  { blacklist: [0, 1, 2] },
  { blacklist: [2, 3] }
];

console.log(blacklistTerms.flatMap(x => x.blacklist));
```